# Docker run doesn't work as part of a terraform startup script

Tags: azure, docker, terraform

I'm using terraform to provision a bunch of machines at once.  Each one should run the same docker container.  The startup script looks like this:

```
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc -Y
sudo apt-get update -Y
sudo apt-get install \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg-agent \
    software-properties-common -Y

curl https://get.docker.com | sh && sudo systemctl --now enable docker

sudo docker build -t dockertest /path/to/dockerfile
sudo docker run --gpus all -it -v /path/to/mount:/usr/src/app dockertest script.py -b 03
```

Basically it installs docker and then builds the container and then runs it.

Only the last line doesn't work.  If I ssh into the machine, it works fine.  But not as part of the startup script.

How can I get it to work as part of the startup script?  It's a hassle to ssh into each of a swarm of machines.

Comment: Is this being ran as cloud-init/user data or something similar? Or as a remote-exec provisioner? Can you share your Terraform code as an [mcve] please? Ideally this should just be the VM creation and how you are executing this script.

Comment: per syslog, it looks like it's done via cloud_init.  No idea about the terraform MRE.  It's a huge repo that the engineer made.  I as the data scientist just change stuff in startup.sh (above) and terraform.tfvars

Comment: It seems like you'd need to have the `sudo docker run` command instead be something that created a service (eg via systemd) and then start that and enable it (so that it will start on reboot) as well.

Comment: That'll get me started

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else encounters this problem:  the solution is simply to take `-it` out of the `docker run` command.